# How to get regions to plot as graphics?

Tags: graphics, regions

I want to put an annulus in my graphics object. How can I format a region difference into a graphics primitive?

```
a=1;b=5;
Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0,0},b],Disk[{0,0},a]]] (*works*)
Graphics[{Rectangle[{5,5}], Blue,Rectangle[{-5,-5}],RegionDifference[Disk[{0,0},b],Disk[{0,0},a]]}](*doesn't work*)
Head[RegionDifference[Disk[{0,0},b],Disk[{0,0},a]]] (* wrong object type *)
Head[Disk[]]
```

Comment: Why not use [`Annulus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annulus)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Rectangle[{5, 5}], Blue, Rectangle[{-5, -5}], 
  First @ RegionPlot @ RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, b], Disk[{0, 0}, a]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 1; b = 5;
Show[Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{4, 4}], {Red, Rectangle[{-5, -5}]}}], 
Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, b], Disk[{0, 0}, a]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Graphics[Annulus[{0, 0}, {.5, 1}]]
```

(* Oh... just saw @Carl Woll's equivalent solution *)

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica 12, [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion)/[`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) objects act as graphics primitives in [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics). So, one idea is to just add [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion) to your [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference) call:

```
a=1;b=5;
Graphics[{
    Rectangle[{5,5}], 
    Blue, Rectangle[{-5,-5}],
    Green, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
        RegionDifference[Disk[{0,0},b],Disk[{0,0},a]], 
        MaxCellMeasure->.1
    ]
}]
```

[image]

One nice feature is that you can control the color of the annulus using graphics directives as usual. This is much more difficult with the other answers.